# d3js: Get hover overlay over multiple graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a set of graphs that can be dynamically added and removed from the page. Each one has an invisible 'rect' element appended to the base svg hosting each graph, and on that rect element I can append mouseover elements. However, these are all limited to the single svg/rect that the mouse is hovering over; I'd like to extend them to cover all visible graphs. Here's the main code affecting that:

```
var focus = svg.append('g') // An invisible layer over the top. Problem is, it only overlays on one graph at a time...
            .style('display', 'none');
svg.append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("pointer-events", "all")
            .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
            .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
            .on("mousemove", mousemove);

// append the x line
        focus.append("line")
            .attr("class", "x")
            .style("stroke", "blue")
            .style("stroke-dasharray", "3,3")
            .style("opacity", 0.5)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("y2", height);

function mousemove() {                            
            var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),         
                i = bisectDate(dataset, x0, 1),              
                d0 = dataset[i - 1],                         
                d1 = dataset[i],                             
                d = x0 - d0.time > d1.time - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.select(".x")
                .attr("transform", function() { 
                    return "translate(" + x(d.time) + "," + rightDomain(symbol, d) + ")"; 
                })
                .attr("y2", height - y(d[symbol]));
}
```

All of this is inside a forEach() loop, where it loops over an array containing the names of the graphs to be shown, so multiple graphs (albeit in their separate svgs) show up.

I also have a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/s4K84f5HGRjHFWMwiuIA?p=preview. I'm not sure why it's failing to work since I've copied and pasted my code, which I know works elsewhere.

Edit: I've managed to attach another svg element to the body but for some reason I can't get it to overlay on top of the existing svgs (the graphs). Here's my code (where I've tried several ways of adjusting the position):

```
var overlay = d3.select('html')
                .append('div')
                .attr('height', function() { return (symbols.length - 1) * 135 + 130; })
                .attr('width', 1000)
                .attr('z-index', 2)
                //.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + extraBuffer/2 + ')');
                //.attr('x', margin.left)
                //.attr('y', extraBuffer/2);
                .attr('position', 'absolute')
                .attr('top', '20')
                .attr('right', '40');
```

Looking at this in chrome devtools I always see it below existing graphs, even if I explicitly set its x/y values.

Comment: Well you know how many SVGs you have and how big they are, so you could add a `div` or something like that which covers them all.

Comment: That would have to be done at the end of the graph-adding loop, I'd assume... would it be svg.append('div'), simply?

Comment: No, append it to the HTML document, not to any of the individual SVGs.

Comment: So... html.append('div') at the end of the loop?

Comment: If `html` is your HTML document, yes.

Comment: I got the extra svg attached, but I can't get it to overlay the existing graphs... OP updated with details.

Comment: Wait, where did the SVG come from? Anyway, you have to set its position as well so that it covers all the graphs.

Comment: I thought I'd need an extra SVG to append the hover elements to, I changed it to a group element. I set its position explicitly but it still remained below the other graphs...

Comment: Well there are several ways of doing this, but my approach would be to append a `div` on top of everything else for this.

Comment: I tried that, it just ended up below everything else. How exactly would you make it hover over the existing graphs?

Comment: Set the `z-index` appropriately.

Comment: Is there a z-index attribute I can modify to do that?

Comment: Yes, this is an attribute that you can set in the usual manner.

Comment: So, something like... `d3.select('html').append('div').attr('z', 2);` would do the trick? Would it also need `.attr('x', 50).attr('y', 40) to get it over the existing svgs?

Comment: `z-index`, not `z`. And yes, you would also need to set its position. You should be able to find out easily how to do that :)

Comment: I still can't get it to work... OP updated.